# How to dismiss the PushViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios5

I have 10 viewControllers in my app. I have pushed all these viewControllers using pushViewController method of NavigationController on NEXT button clicked of each viewController.

I have used code for that as ;

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someView animated:YES];
```

Now i want to jump back to the rootViewController from the 10th child(viewController).

How can i do this ?

Please help me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try to use ..

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this code:

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:NO];//Use the desired index instead of 1 here
```

for just go back to last screen use this

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` 
for particular view ..

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSInteger index = 0;
 for (UIViewController *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
 if([view.nibName isEqualToString:@"RootViewController"])//put any `XIB name` where u want to navigate 
    break;
index = index + 1;
 }
 [[self navigationController] popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

To go back to the previous screen (last element of the view controller stack), pop the view controller:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

**FOR SWIFT 4**

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: yeah...i see later the real question inside the post.  Answer update.